# m3u8 & RTMP & RTSP Playbacks on FlowPlayer or JWPlayer?

Tags: jwplayer, rtsp, rtmp, flowplayer, m3u8

Actually mine is Wowza behind. It comes out with following streams for my Application:

```
http://.................../mychannel/playlist.m3u8
rtmp://.................../mychannel&streamType=live
rtsp://.................../mychannel
http://.................../mychannel/Manifest
```

I am fine with using native HTML5 Video Tag for `HTTP`, Flash Embed for `RTMP`, and direct RTSP link for `RTSP` Streams. (Manifest/Smooth is ignored as i still don't know how to play/setup with Silverlight)

But **how can i** properly setup this streams `all together` in one pure Player?
Like `FlowPlayer` or `JWPlayer`

Thanks & appreciate so much for kind helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting up something like this:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29394/hls-with-mp4-fallback

Just make the 1st source RTMP, 2nd source the HLS stream, then set up a 3rd source outside of the player in an  tag, as recommended here (for Android) - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28856/using-apple-hls-streaming

Comment: Hi Ethan, thank you so much for the help. But honestly i do not understand your page yet, as obviously it is showing only the `m3u8` setting. Sorry i'm a dummy but where is about `rtmp` and where is about `rtsp`? Can you just please, paste the final codes here? (Appreciate so so much)

Comment: I set up like this, but not working:     

<div id='theplayer'>
      <a href="rtsp://xx.xx.xx.xx:1935/liveedge/mychannel">RTSP</a>
    </div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
         jwplayer("theplayer").setup({
            playlist: [{
                sources: [
                   { file: 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:1935/liveedge/mychannel/playlist.m3u8' }
                ]
            }],
            height:480,
            width: 854
         });
    </script>

Comment: Do you have a link to where you are running this?

Comment: Link? You mean the player location? I'm sorry to share this. But as i mentioned, all the links above are working fine with respective default players. (No problem with streams)

Comment: I mean a link to the player embed. I would like to see this so I can debug properly.